# Can tidyverse separate_rows() retain information before each delimiter?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm looking to use separate_rows() to create a row for each assembly and taxonomic rank in a data frame so that I can summarise their genome lengths at each taxonomic rank while retaining the full string up to each semi-colon separator.
I have managed to do this fine with a bunch of if_else statements inside a mutate() and it works but I would like to know if anybody has a more elegant solution that I could use for similar situations in the future.

The input, my current code, and output for a single assembly example are included below - this would be used on thousands of assemblies in practice.

Thanks,
Calum

```
df <- data.frame(Assembly = 'GCA_00001', Length = 5370060, Taxonomy = 'd__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Bacillales;f__Bacillaceae_G;g__Bacillus_A;s__Baci
llus_A anthracis')

df %>%
  mutate(Lineage = Taxonomy) %>%
  separate_rows(Taxonomy, sep = ';') %>%
  mutate(Rank = str_remove(Taxonomy, '__.*') %>% toupper) %>%
  group_by(Taxonomy, Rank, Lineage) %>% 
  summarise(MeanLength = mean(Length),
            MedianLength = median(Length)) %>%
  mutate(Rank = ordered(Rank, levels = c('D', 'P', 'C', 'O', 'F', 'G', 'S'))) %>%
  arrange(Rank) %>%
  mutate(Lineage = if_else(Rank == 'D', str_remove(Lineage, ';p__.*'),
                           if_else(Rank == 'P', str_remove(Lineage, ';c__.*'),
                                   if_else(Rank == 'C', str_remove(Lineage, ';o__.*'),
                                           if_else(Rank == 'O', str_remove(Lineage, ';f__.*'),
                                                   if_else(Rank == 'F', str_remove(Lineage, ';g__.*'),
                                                           if_else(Rank == 'G', str_remove(Lineage, ';s__.*'), Lineage)))))))


Taxonomy                  Rank   Lineage                                                                                                     MeanLength   MedianLength
-----------------------   ----   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   ----------   ------------
d__Bacteria               D      d__Bacteria                                                                                                 5370060      5370060
p__Firmicutes             P      d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes                                                                                   5370060      5370060
c__Bacilli                C      d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli                                                                        5370060      5370060
o__Bacillales             O      d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Bacillales                                                          5370060      5370060
f__Bacillaceae_G          F      d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Bacillales;f__Bacillaceae_G                                         5370060      5370060
g__Bacillus_A             G      d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Bacillales;f__Bacillaceae_G;g__Bacillus_A                           5370060      5370060
s__Bacillus_A anthracis   S      d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Bacillales;f__Bacillaceae_G;g__Bacillus_A;s__Bacillus_A anthracis   5370060      5370060
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could potentially use the `accumulate` function to help out here. note your Taxonomy would need to be in the right order for this to work. rough code below:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Assembly = 'GCA_00001', Length = 5370060, Taxonomy = 'd__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Bacillales;f__Bacillaceae_G;g__Bacillus_A;s__Bacillus_A anthracis')

df %>% 
  separate_rows(Taxonomy, sep = ";") %>% 
  mutate(Rank = toupper(str_sub(Taxonomy, 1, 1))) %>% 
  mutate(Lineage = accumulate(.x = paste0(Taxonomy, ";"), .f = paste0))
```

Comment: Thanks CourtesyBus - looks like it is what I am looking for